# Is it possible to use generator for any <property> in Hibernate mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
<id name="message_id" column="message_id">
   <generator class="native"/>
</id>
```

Above typical example of using generator for ID column, I need auto-generating column in my project but not ID.

Comment: The purpose of the generator is to generate a unique identifier for domain objects. What other purpose would you need it for?

Comment: Only to guarantee unique identifier

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate has a concept of [generated properties](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-generated), though it can be used only when values are generated at the database side, i.e. it's an equivalent of `<generator class = "identity" />`, other generators cannot be used:

```
<property name = "message_id" generated = "insert" />
```

Comment: thanx, the IDE suggests me this parameter, I will try

Comment: I use this mapping, but all records have message_id = NULL. How to make Hibernate generate some value?

Comment: @slavig: I though my answer was pretty clear: this approach can be used **only when values are generated at the database side**, for example, by trigger.

Comment: This doesn't work on its own. You need a trigger on the db side to get it to work